# How to change date format and add date in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a date in this format 18/02/2014 I just need to add 7 days to it. Anyone can help please? I have tried in this way

```
var cur_date = new Date("27/02/2014");
var next_date = cur_date.setDate(cur_date.getDate() + 14);
alert(next_date)
```

but it returns this: 1458064800000

Comment: Many can help, but Are you willing to help yourself? If yes, post some code which you tried.

Comment: Hint: have a look at `Date()`.

Comment: I have tried in this way var cur_date = new Date("27/02/2014");
var next_date = cur_date.setDate(cur_date.getDate() + 14);
alert(next_date) but it returns this: 1458064800000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
  var date  =  '18/02/2014'.split('/');   //   convert to array
  date[0]   =  parseInt(date[0])+7;       // add 7 days
  date      =  date.join('/');            // reconstruct date
```

Comment: just another necessity please

Comment: I just need the date format converted to 02/18/2014 is this possible? and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

in your JQuery you can try :

```
var v = new Date(2014, 02, 18); 
v.setDate(v.getDate() + 7);
```

parameters are a string carefully following the notation :

```
NameObject = new Date(year, month, day)
```

Three parameters are comma-separated integers. 
Omitted parameters are set to zero by default